# Overflow: hidden on 2 circle

Tags: html, css

I went create one triangle with an overflow hidden to hide the parts that go beyond the 2 circles but I'm only coming pour 1 circle but no two....
[image]

```
<div class="big_rond">
        <div class="small_rond">
            <ul>
                <li class="first_triangle"></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
.big_rond {
    background:#bfd70e;
    border-radius:50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border:2px solid #679403; 
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.small_rond {
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:2px solid red; 
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30%;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

li {
}

.first_triangle {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left: 20%;
    border-width: 80px 300px 80px 0;
    border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
}
```

I went my 2 circles hide the parts that go beyond [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that triangle is child of small-rond div, so it always had the same z-index or overflow than small circle div.
Maybe you could use another HTML DOM tree.

```
<div class="big_rond">
   <ul>
      <li class="first_triangle"></li>
   </ul> 
</div>
<div class="small_rond"><div>
```

Use `z-index` property in css too, adding this too elements to your css code

```
.small-rond{
    z-index: 50;
  }

.first_triangle{
   z-index: 40;
 }
```